# Magento Store get removed

Tags: magento-1.7

www.grizb.com

My site disappears and show cpanel page, I have done nothing,   and internal page shows 404 error, Can anyone help me what happened and what to do to make it live, site url redirect to " http://grizb.com/customer/account/login/ " but now whole site is gone.

Comment: There isn't really enough information for anyone here to be able to help you. If your site was working before, then something likely changed in your hosting settings. I would recommend contacting Host Gator for help.